Manhwa where a husband cut down his wife, who transformed into a tree
I watched a YouTube short about this particular manhwa. It was a long time ago. All I can remember is that when the male lead found his wife, she had become a tree and told the male lead to cut her down, which would eventually kill her, so he did what she said. Please forgive me; that is all I can remember.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.
